# In PHP7, why can a child class's method define a return type when the overridden parent method does not?

Tags: php, inheritance

Consider the following code snippet:

```php
class Foo
{
    public function fooMethod()
    {
        return [];
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function fooMethod(): array
    {
        return ['something'];
    }
}
```

This works without any errors (tested in PHP7.4 and PHP7.3). Why does PHP not enforce the method signature of the child to be the same as the parent (i.e. no return type)? Is there a valid reason why PHP allows this, or is it a bug? My guess is that by not declaring it in the parent, we're essentially saying it could return "mixed", thus any return type would be valid, but I'm curious to know the reason.

Comment: `Foo->fooMethod()` can return anything because it's return type is not specifically defined. In this case  it's an empty array `[]` . This is for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you can also declare the child  as `public function fooMethod(): int` and there is no error, so it's not that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**PHP Manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) states:

> Note:
>
> When overriding a parent method, the child's method must match any return type declaration on the parent. If the parent doesn't define a return type, then the child method may do so.

Note the line: *"If the parent doesn't define a return type, then the child method may do so"*

So if you look at your example; the parent method in class Foo has no return type defined, so the child method in class Bar can set any return type it wishes.

---

## A:

```
class Foo
{
    public function fooMethod()
    {
        return []; // returns an array. Type expected: any.
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function fooMethod(): array
    {
        return ['something']; // returns an array, type expected: array
    }
}
```

## B:

This one works fine because there is no pre-existing expectation of type so when the child class sets a type, it's not overwriting anything.

```
class Foo
{
    public function fooMethod()
    {
        return []; // returns an array, type expected any
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function fooMethod(): string
    {
        return "horses"; // returns a string, type expected: string
    }
}
```

## C:

This one will cause problems (*ie your evil military moonbase will be destroyed with the loss of all hands*) because the child is trying to overwrite the already defined return type property of the parent method.

```
class Foo
{
    public function fooMethod(): int
    {
        return 874; // returns an int, type expected is int.
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function fooMethod(): array
    {
        return ['something']; // returns an array, type expected int
    }
}
```